# К чему может получить доступ WEB приложение

Tags: javascript, php, linux, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

К каким ресурсам может получить доступ WEB приложение? Имеется ввиду гео, веб-камера и так далее.
Интересует как классический вариант приложения так и PWA WEB приложение.

Спасибо за помощь!